# Using Bazaar to handle Website Versioning

Tags: bazaar

I imagine this is a pretty basic question but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

I develop websites. In the past I've handled all the live files manually and it stinks, of course. I've been hoping Bazaar could add some power and organization to the way we work.

Right now, I work with a local server on my laptop and want to gracefully push data onto the live server. Currently, I'm doing the following:

---

Local machine:

bzr push sftp://user@server/path/to/project/BZR/live

On server:

rm -r /path/to/project/live

bzr branch /path/to/project/BZR/live

---

Is there anyway to get the Local files live from the push?

Otherwise, is a branch to the live path correct?

Is there anyway to get Bazaar to just update changed files in the live path so that I don't have to delete /live each time?

Right now I have to manually edit .htaccess with each upload. If I didn't have to delete /live, I imagine I could tell bzr to ignore it and all would take care of itself.

Thanks for your help!

-Nicky

Comment: Do you need to develop on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check bzr-upload plugin, and also push-and-update plugin.